# How do you select two counts in a single query?

Tags: mysql

I'm having some trouble with this one thing I'm working on in php(though I don't think it matters much).

I've got a table called `apples`. It has a column called `good apples` that has values `0 or 1`. I want to do an sql query that I want to use to display `good apples=1` out of total apples in that table. How do I count ALL and `good apples=1` in a single query, if that's the way to do this?

Comment: Do you have to sum the results of that column or is the value the same for all rows?

Comment: always remember to mark as answered if it helps you solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

`select sum(good_apples) as good_count, count(*) as all_count from apples`

Answer (score 2):

You can always use MySQL conditional count.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(goodapples) as totalCount, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN apples.goodapples = 1 THEN 1 END) 
AS 
    goodapplecount 
FROM 
    apple;
```

Comment: This Method is much preferred because due to the ability to capture any "CASE" you may want to define.  Not that it is applicable for this case, but you even have the ability to "Weight" your counts.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this will do:

```
 SELECT SUM(good_apples), count(good_apples) FROM apple_table
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
SELECT b_good_apple, COUNT(b_good_apple) AS apple_count FROM apples
GROUP BY b_good_apple;
```

so that you get the "good apple" and "bad apple" counts. Obviously, the sum of the two is your total.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT count(*) as count,sum(good_apple) FROM `Apple`
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```sql
SELECT COUNT(good_apples) AS goodApples 
    FROM apples WHERE good_apples = 1 
    UNION SELECT COUNT(*) AS totalApples FROM apples
```

Comment: This is not good, because the results are placed on two lines.  The end result should be two values on one line.